# Top web-hosting sites with jQuery support?

Tags: web-hosting, jquery, web-services

I am looking to start building a website and I am looking for some good web hosting companies that gives the best bang for the buck.

I had been reading on some websites in regards to some web hosting companies having the inability to run scripts on their servers (jQuery) which causes a big problem since the website I am in the process of making is very jQuery driven.

Can anyone recommend some good web hosting companies that they had good experience with?

Comment: Don't post sites like that. Generally web host review sites, especially spammy looking ones with spammy domains, are nothing but affiliate marketing traps. How can you expect to get honest reviews from a company who earns affiliate commission on every referral to the web hosts they "review"? Look for non-sketchy sites that host _user_ reviews. Webhostingreviews.com is probably less sketchy than most.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery is client-side, so it operates independently of server. Your hosting environment shouldn't really have any effect on how jQuery works (Unless you're doing something unique with AJAX or some other type of JavaScript that interacts with the server)

Languages such as PHP (The language scripts such as WordPress, Drupal and Joomla! are programmed in), however, *are* server-side and does require special server permissions. Most professional webhosts will have support for whatever server-side scripting language you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

While you should not have any issues hosting jQuery on your own server, it would be a good idea to reference the jQuery library from Google's CDN to improve performance of your web pages ([read detailed explanation](http://encosia.com/2010/09/15/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/)).

47 of the Alexa top 1,000 reference jQuery from the Google CDN.